# Pigeon Hole theory with 10 ints

Tags: elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

If I have a set of 10 integers, is it possible to prove there are two that the difference is by a multiple of nine?

My instinct says you can find two that differ by a multiple of 5 but not 9

Comment: How many possible remainders are there when you divide a number by $9$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig There are 9 possible remainders?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If you divide a number by $9$, there are nine possible remainders.  Thus, in any set of ten numbers, there must be two with the same remainder when divided by $9$.